# Cast a column of a 2D Object array as a 1D String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, casting

I am trying to cast a 2D Object array column as a 1D String array; I have no problem getting the data itself, but it is the data types which creates a run-time error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
>   cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

This is an example of the code fragment I am working with:

```
Object[][] currentData = BackOffice.getData();
String[] dataWanted = null;

    for (int i=0; i<currentData.length; i++)
        dataWanted = (String[])currentData[i][1];
```

I thought I could get away with casting using (String[]), but obviously not...
any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do:

```
String[] dataWanted = new String[currentData.length];

for (int i=0; i<currentData.length; i++)
    dataWanted[i] = currentData[i][1];
```

Comment: Yaaay, that is pretty much what I wanted, I can now happily cast using (String) before currentData[i][1]; thanks! Of course I needed to use dataWanted[i]... obvious!

Answer (score 1):

`currentData` is a 2D array of Objects, so `currentData[i][1]` evaluates to a single Object. `dataWanted` is an array of Strings. You can't cast a single Object into an array type. Additionally, arrays must be initialized with a size before inserting items. If you'd like to place each Object into the `dataWanted` array you'll want something like this:

```
String[] dataWanted = new String[currentData.length];
for (int i = 0; i < currentData.length; i++) {
    dataWanted[i] = (String)currentData[i][1];
}
```

If this isn't what you're trying to accomplish, then please edit your question to be more specific.